# Read all characters using fread from Matlab to embedded device

Tags: c, matlab, embedded, hex, eof

I am trying to copy data from a file containing HEX characters to my embedded device's SRAM memory over UART from Matlab. The problem is I don't know how to make the program stop treating any of the received characters as a special command.

For eg: the symbol '' has HEX equivalent of 0x20 as per the ASCII table. However,it may happen that my data has this 0x20 somewhere. So, i can't use this as a delimiter for my program.

Please suggest me a way by which all the data from the hex file can be read without causing any such issues.

This is the part of my code.

```
memcpy(((uint8_t*)(SRAM_BASE+i)),&cThisChar,1);
    UARTCharPut(UART0_BASE, cThisChar);
        i++;

    //
    // Stay in the loop until either a CR or LF is received.
    //
    } 
         while((cThisChar != '\n') && (cThisChar != '\r')); // this is where the problem happens!
```

So what should I put a condition for the while loop so that it accepts all characters?

Thanks!

Comment: You say that you have a text file with hex numbers('A', '1'...) which are delimited into separate strings with CR and LF characters? And you want to send this data as a stream of characters omitting any CR and LF?

Comment: No..I dont want to omit anything..I have characters like 4B 18 60 OA and so on...so as soon as OA is encountered it stops!!

Comment: How do you open the file?

Comment: Are you characters are divided into pairs A6[space]1F? And what does the OA sequence mean?

Comment: May be it is 0(zero)A but someone made a mistake during a creation of the file replacing 0 with O?

Comment: Ah yes..sorry yes its 0=(Zero) and not O alphabet! Yes characters are aggregated as bytes.

Comment: The file is being opened by A = fopen('C:\Users\admin\Workspace\STELLARIS-LM4F120_00_210214_104000_0001_temp_025.bin');

Comment: @self.please suggest an edit. Thank you.

Comment: Should this file's characters be send exactly as they are in the file?   You are sending them to the microcontoller using some Matlab functions. What are these function? Does your send-function sends data per byte? What is the microcontoller's code? Is it already burned in the device? Or you can change it(or it('memcpy((..') is the code)? What is the PC(Matlab) code? What do you mean by 'as soon as my program sees this it stops' ?

Comment: Describe your system as: (1)PC with Matlab connected through (2)UART to the (3)Microcontroller. PC(1) opens file(4) with some data(5). Data(5) is sent through (2) ti the (3). And so on. Can you describe it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically,this is all what I wanted to achieve! Thanks for your effort anyways!

```
signed char cThisChar;
    while (cThisChar != EOF);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to get the end of file by its content.
Get its size and use a counter instead.

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
long int fsize = 0;
long int fptr = 0;

/* Open file. */
/* todo: Open file here. */

/* Get file size. */
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
fsize = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

/* Process file data. */
while (fptr < fsize) {
    /* todo: Do your stuff here. */
    ++fptr;
}

/* Close file. */
/* todo: Close file here. */
```

Comment: As I understand the problem is on the microcontroller side of the system. The microcontroller is unable to understand when there is no more data to read from UART. Or it stops getting the data too soon and synchronous UART in the PC program just halts any further progress. One of them.

Comment: @darkundar: basically I am getting characters in cThisChar variable. i wanted to use this but I think nobody understood my question well and downsized my question ratings. Anyways I am posting the solution.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: NO the problem was NOT on the µcontroller side. it was related to the buffer size mostly which was kept high so a number of bytes were getting lost also.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the solution.

```
while (j < 2048)
{
   do
   {
      //
      // Read a character using the blocking read function.  This function
      // will not return until a character is available.
      //
      cThisChar = UARTCharGet(UART0_BASE);

      //
      // Write the same character using the blocking write function.  This
      // function will not return until there was space in the FIFO and
      // the character is written.
      //
      memcpy(((uint8_t*)(SRAM_BASE+i)),&cThisChar,1);
      UARTCharPut(UART0_BASE, cThisChar);
      i++;

      //
      // Stay in the loop until either a CR or LF is received.
      //
   } //while((cThisChar != '\n') && (cThisChar != '\r'));
   while (i<17);
   j++;
}
```

This is part of the code from the microcontroller side. After repeated iterations, I found out that using a buffer value of 16 was the best option. j is the outer loop counter = 32768/16 = 2048. by this I can write all the 32768 bytes in packets of 16 bytes.

And now the corresponding MATLAB version of the code:

```
while(true)

    txdata = fread(A,**16**,'uint8','ieee-be');
    %[my_count_rows, my_count_columns]=size(txdata);
    %Convert to decimal format
    %txdata_dec = hex2dec(txdata);
    %Write using the UINT8 data format

    **fwrite(obj1,txdata(1:16),'uint8');**
    if txdata > 32768
        break;
    end    
end
```